# Как осуществить подключение пакета summernote node.js к проекту?

Tags: node.js, laravel, openserver

Пытаюсь установить пакет summernote из node.js на локальный сервер (OpenServer) в проекте laravel.

1. Сама установка node.js была ясна просто. Однако, сразу возникли вопросы, почему в консоли cmd можно увидеть версию node и npm, а во встроенной консоли OpenServer такое не отображает даже, говоря, что неизвестная команда?
2. Второй момент, когда я все же устанавливаю node_modules в корневую папку своего проекта (с ларавел) появляется соответствующая папка. Я пытаюсь вызвать команды для работы с summernote из файла своего скрипта, который подключен к проекту.

```js
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');

    require('summernote');
    require('summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.css');
    require('summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.js');
    require('summernote/dist/lang/summernote-ru-RU.js');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Наталкиваюсь сразу же на ошибку в первой строке:

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
```

Пишет:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

В связи с чем возникает вопрос, как правильно обращаться к пакетам `npm` и `node` (примечание: они успешно установлены в папке)? Учитывая, что это laravel и публичная папка считается public в поддиректории корневого проекта. Подскажите, как правильно подключить пакет summernote от `node.js` для улучшения формы редактора. В чем мои ошибки при работе с `node.js`?

Comment: require - должно выполняться в node.js, а вы скорее всего пытаетесь это выполнить на клиенте(браузере)

Comment: @SwaD, команду require я выполняю в скрипте js подключенном к моему проекту. Это же вызов библиотек из node.js, как же тогда работать с этим?